# How to export HAXE code to other languages?

Tags: haxe

I'm using Haxe on the HAXE IDE, HIDE. I can simply create code for any language, but I don't know how to export it. It didn't have any export options, and no tutorials explain this. How do I export it?

Answer (score 3):

If you choose *project > build* or *project > run* the project will be exported to the *Export* folder inside the project directory. I don't know what project you exactly started but in the *project > project options* you can find which platform you are targeting.

If you want to export to multiple platforms, you have to alter the hxml files, and instruct the compiler to also export to different platforms. You can find the basic usage here: http://haxe.org/documentation/introduction/compiler-usage.html